# Log in to AWS using a keypair

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to log in to my Amazon AWS instance using SSH. I just created the instance, and created a new keyPair with the instance. I placed that KeyPair in the directory where I try to ssh from.

I do `$ ssh -i myKeyPair.pem ec2-user@ec2-11-111-111-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com`.

It gives this output:

```
debug1: Trying private key: myKeyPair.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Try making `myKeyPair.pem` readable only by owner with `chmod 600 myKeyPair.pem; chown youruser myKeyPair.pem`. ssh is pretty fussy about using key files that may be compromised because other users have read/write access.

Answer (score 0):

Add -vvv to the end of your ssh statement.

This will allow you to see the verbose output of the ssh command, especially if you have the key set to the wrong path locally or if the instance is rejecting your key.

I also see that you are trying to log in as ec2-user. This is the valid default user for amazon Linux AMI's. If you are using another flavor of distro then there are other default users:
amazon Linux -> ec2-user
Ubuntu -> Ubuntu
Debian -> admin

If you are using a private or public Ami that someone else has created the you might need to find the default user for that instance as the normal default users may have been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Which AMI are you using? There's a bunch that expect you to log in as user "root" instead of "ec2-user"